# Grids displaying relative instead of global coordinates in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinates, print-composer, layouts, wgs84

I have a set of three zoomed-in maps I need to plot grids for. They need to be in degrees, minutes, seconds and relative to the global standard. The grids I was able to plot all show relative coordinates, starting at 0 on the corner of the map. See example below.

[image]

My project CRS EPSG:32632, grid CRS is EPSG:4326. X interval: 4 centimetres; Y interval: 2 centimetres. Map scale is 5 Km. I am using QGIS 3.32.2 'Lima'.

Tutorials display global coordinates automatically. All questions I have seen here so far have the opposite problem - they want to use relative coordinates instead of global. I haven't figured out how to display the opposite and haven't found any option that does so.

Answer (score 2):

Click "Modify Grid" button under "Map Item Properties > Grids" and change "Appearance > Interval" value to "Map Units" instead of "Milimeter" or "Centimeter".

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this option makes my grid disappear completely (it's why I used cm in the first place) and no value of X and Y seems to solve it.

Comment: Try different  (X, Y) interval values.